# Backbone route changed event

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to track changes to the routes via:

```
define([
    'jquery', 
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'router',
    'text!templates/sidebar.html'], 
    function($, _, Backbone, Router, SidebarTemplate) {
        var SidebarView = Backbone.View.extend({
            el: $('#sidebar'),

            initialize: function() {
                _.bindAll(this, 'render');
                this.listenTo(Router, 'route', this.routeChanged, this);
            },

            events: {
                'click a' : 'navigated'     
            },

            render: function() {
                var cTem = _.template(SidebarTemplate);
                this.$el.html(cTem);
            },

            routeChanged: function(router, route) {
                console.log(route);
            },

            navigated: function(a) {
                this.$('li').removeClass();
                $(a.currentTarget).parent().addClass('active')
            }
        });
        return SidebarView;
    });
```

I am getting:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_listenId' of undefined
```

on this line:

```
this.listenTo(Router, 'route', this.routeChanged, this);
```

I think it is because there's circular dependency. Is this indeed the case? How can I fix this?

Relevant source for router.js :

```
define([
    'jquery', 
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'views/dashboard',
    'views/users',
    'views/venues',
    'views/payments',
    'views/header',
    'views/sidebar',
    'views/signup',
    'views/login'], 
    function($, _, Backbone, DashboardView, UsersView, VenuesView, PaymentsView, HeaderView, SidebarView, SignupView, LoginView) {
        var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({

            initialize: function() {
                self.sidebarView = new SidebarView();
                self.headerView = new HeaderView();

                self.sidebarView.render();
                self.headerView.render();
            },

            routes: {
                '': 'showDashbaord',
                'dashboard': 'showDashbaord',
                'users': 'showUsers',
                'venues': 'showVenues',
                'payments': 'showPayments',
                'login': 'showLogin',
                'signup': 'showSignup',
                'logout': 'logout'
            }
        });
        return new Router();
    });
```

Thanks!

Comment: I might check that your Router is the object you expect it to be: what is Router.listenId?

Comment: @DanBaker Router is undefined. I think it's because of circular dependency.

Comment: A work around could be to tie Router to your application namespace ie MyProj.router  ( i dont use requirejs)

Comment: What's the code for router.js?

Comment: @LynHeadley updated with relevant source of router.js - Notice how I am intializing sidebarView in initialize function. I think that's the problem. Because sidebarView in turn wants to require router.js

Answer (score 0):

Yep, looks circular. Try this:

```
define([
    'require',
    'jquery', 
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'router',
    'text!templates/sidebar.html'], 
    function(require, $, _, Backbone, Router, SidebarTemplate) {
      return function () {
        Router = require("router");
```

Then when using SidebarView from other modules, you'll need:

var SideBarViewInst = SideBarView()

This will delay the import until all modules are loaded.

Comment: Uncaught Error: Module name "router" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])